# In C++, how to create a map whose value is a protobuf extension indentifier

Tags: c++, inheritance, dictionary, key, protocol-buffers

In protobuf, we have several options to implement inheritance. "Nested extensions" is one of them:
http://www.indelible.org/ink/protobuf-polymorphism/

Here what is interesting is how to read a serialized file. We have to create a Map to correspond the Animal.type to its extension identifier in order to cast an animal into a correct Dog or Cat. However, in the example provided by the website above, the language used is Python. It then means that a Map can be initialized without specifying the type of key or the type of the value. And it works well:

```
# Unpack the serialized bytes.
animal = Animal()
animal.ParseFromString(bytes)

# Determine the appropriate extension type to use.
extension_map = { Animal.Cat: Cat.animal, Animal.Dog: Dog.animal }
extension = animal.Extensions[extension_map[animal.type]]
```

However, in order to implement such a map in C++, the key type and value type is mandatory. So, what type shall I use for the value in order that the two different Extension Identifiers can be stored into the same map?

`Map<Animal::Type, ::google::protobuf::internal::ExtensionIdentifier>`?

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, obviously.

I shall also copy paste the writing paradigm here:
 from animals_pb2 import *

```
# Construct the polymorphic base message type.
animal = Animal()
animal.type = Animal.Cat

# Create the subclass type by referencing the appropriate extension type.
# Note that this uses the self-referential field (Cat.animal) from within
# nested message extension.
cat = animal.Extensions[Cat.animal]
cat.declawed = True

# Serialize the complete message contents to a string.  It will end up
# looking roughly like this: [ type [ declawed ] ]
bytes = animal.SerializeToString()
```

The Extensions() function can enable us to get its extension using the extension's identifier.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to store a map of constructed extension objects in a map to have access to after parsing the message.

In that case, there are [variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html) and [any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html) types in boost, [poco libraries](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Any.html) and some more. You could make the key-type fixed (i.e. enum type or string) and the value type a variant type:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct Animal {
    std::string type;
};

struct Dog : public Animal {
    constexpr static const char* TYPE = "Dog";
    void bark() const {
        std::cout<<"bow"<<std::endl;
    }
};

struct Cat : public Animal {
    constexpr static const char* TYPE = "Cat";
    void meow() const {
        std::cout<<"meow"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

a factory to get the extensions from a message:

```
template <typename Animal,typename Message>
std::unique_ptr<Animal> get_extension(Message m) {
    try {
        Animal a( boost::any_cast<Animal>(m[Animal::TYPE]) );
        //for simplicity
        return std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Animal(a));
    } catch (...) {
        return std::unique_ptr<Animal>();
    }    
}
```

and the usage:

```
int main()
{
    // simulation of a protobuf message
    std::map<std::string,boost::any> m;
    m[Dog::TYPE] = Dog();
    m[Cat::TYPE] = Cat();

    // the generic interface to the message extensions
    auto dog = get_extension<Dog>(m);
    if (dog)
        dog->bark();
    auto cat = get_extension<Cat>(m);
    if (cat)
        cat->meow();
}
```

[compile@coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c6abf34bb494bd3)

Update: [version 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c43ceb4839799aa) with a common interface for animals

What may actually be the task is that you have a message with extensions, and you want to create the objects dynamically. In the second version, you can also "speak to the animals" via the same interface:

```
struct Animal {
    virtual void speak() const = 0;
    virtual ~Animal(){}
};

struct Dog : public Animal {
    constexpr static const char* TYPE = "Dog";
    virtual void speak() const {
        std::cout<<"bow"<<std::endl;
    }
};
// ... etc
```

a simplistic factory for typed deserialized animals:

```
struct AnimalRegistry {
    std::map<std::string , std::function<std::unique_ptr<Animal>()>> creators;

    template<typename A>
    void register_creator() {
        creators[A::TYPE] = []() { return std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new A); };
    }

    template<typename Message>
    std::unique_ptr<Animal> create(Message m) {
        return creators[m.animal_type]();
    }
};
```

and the usage would be just slightly different:

```
int main()
{
    AnimalRegistry registry;
    registry.register_creator<Dog>();
    registry.register_creator<Cat>();

    Message received_message { "Dog" /*this is a part of your protobuf*/ };

    auto dog = registry.create(received_message);
    if (dog)
        dog->speak();

    Message another_message { "Cat" };
    auto cat = registry.create(another_message);
    if (cat)
        cat->speak();
}
```

Comment: If you want to get a Dog instance, you have to cast from boost::any to Dog. It means that you should have known already to what exact type your boost::any type correspond to. If, for example, you read an object created by others, you can hardly know to which type you should cast your boost::any type. In the example I provided, it can automatically cast the object using the ExtensionIdentifier with the Extensions() function.

Comment: @pptime exactly, c++ compile time defined types. In c++ if you want to use a type's interface, you need to know the type for making the call. I don't see a contradiction of your comment and my solution proposition. I'll try to show a simple factory code, so that you see what I mean.

Comment: as you were trying to comment: yes, you need to know that ´dog´ is of type ´Dog´. How would you call the method ´Dog::bark´ then? This is a statically typed language. If you want to use a single interface, use Animal as an interface and dynamically create your object based on registered types. There's still no contradiction with your needs.

Comment: here's ([s. coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c43ceb4839799aa)) a further example, still no "if dog then dog if cat then cat". The 'ifs' check whether the message conversion has succeeded and not to check the type. It is inferred from the message itself.

Comment: you are right. conversion succeeds simply means that it is dog type, not cat type, right? you are right, anyway we should know all the type that we handle to be able to use it.

Comment: @pptime, yes, you can chose between the two versions

Comment: so, is the answer sufficient? Considering to chose it as an answer?